# Determining every automorphism of the first complex quadrant

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to explicitly determine every isomorphism of the first quadrant of the complex plane.

Considering the set $\{ z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(z)>0\text{ and }\Im(z)>0\}$ as the first quadrant, I know that I can map this (using Möbius Transformations) set into the unit disc (this is stated by the Riemann Conformal Mapping Theorem). Using the disc automorphisms I already know I can produce several automorphisms of the first quadrant.

The question is: how can I proof that every automorphism of the first quadrant into the unit disc is a Möbius transform (so I can explicitly determine all of them)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52338/conformal-maps-onto-the-unit-disc-in-mathbbc

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I would even ask for a moderator to mark this as duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I proof that every automorphism of the first quadrant into the unit disc

Let's get the terminology right. The prefix *auto* means "self-". In mathematical context it usually indicates a bijection $X\to X$ with some additional properties (here, being holomorphic). Thus, you can have an "automorphism of $X$", but not an "automorphism of $X$ into $Y$".

A holomorphic bijection $f:X\to Y$  could in principle be called an *isomorphism*, but on this occasion the terminology of abstract algebra did not catch up in analysis. One speaks of biholomorphic maps, or conformal maps.

> Using the disc automorphisms I already know I can produce several automorphisms of the first quadrant.

Not just several, *all of them*. This is a rather general fact: if you know the automorphisms of $Y$ (say, the set  of all holomorphic bijections $\phi:Y\to Y $), and have just one isomorphism $f:X\to Y$, then you get all automorphisms of $X$ in the form $f^{-1}\circ \phi\circ f$, where $\phi$ runs through the automorphisms of $Y$. The reason is simple: if $\psi$ is any automorphism of $X$, then the map $\phi:= f\circ \psi\circ f^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $Y$, and you have $\psi = f^{-1}\circ \phi\circ f$.

Note that nothing in the preceding paragraph depends on what formula $f$ has, or what the word "holomorphic" even means; this is pure *abstract nonsense*.

Answer (score 0):

Let f(z) = z^2.

Let g(z) be the inverse of f(z) along the principle branch of the square root.

Any automorphism of the upper half plane has the form: 
h(z) = (az+b) / (cz+d), with a,b,c,d real and ad-bc > 0.

Then any automorphism of the first quadrent is given by a composition of these three functions: g(h(f(z))).

See the solution at: http://sertoz.bilkent.edu.tr/courses/math302/2011/hwk2-sol.pdf

Comment: [Please MathJax.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  It will make it much easier to parse what you have written (the fractions in the Moebius transformation, in particular).